# Selenium send_keys() not inserting the full date

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to generate historical data table from [Dhaka Stock Exchange](https://www.dsebd.org/data_archive.php). 
Problem is when I am trying to insert a date using the following code-

```
start_date = driver.find_element_by_id('DayEndSumDate1').send_keys("30062019")
```

it only inputs the date partially, i.e. only day and month but not the year like the following image-
[image]

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the HTML for that element look like?  It's an `<input>`?

Comment: It is <input type="date".

Comment: You don't have to use Selenium for this job. The website uses plain old POST requests and returns a static webpage. Let me know if you need pointers.

Comment: But for selenium, you can try setting `value` attribute of date inputs in `2019-07-01` format : https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/3388/40294

Comment: I tried setting the values as 2019-07-01format. It did not work for chrome driver (I really don't know the reason). I later tried putting the date like that with Firefox driver and it worked perfectly.